# How to redirect URLs that do not contain some specific characters by using htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Assume that I have some URL like these:

```
http://mydomaindotcom/abc/123-link.html

http://mydomaindotcom/abc/page/page-link.html
```

Now I want to redirect all URLs like : http://mydomaindotcom/**otherstring**/123-link.html to http://mydomaindotcom/**abc**/123-link.html

or http://mydomaindotcom/**anotherone**/page/page-link.html to http://mydomaindotcom/**abc**/page/page-link.html

It means that the first segment on URL must be [abc], if not, redirect to the [abc]-beginning one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /abc/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What if the urls do not have [abc...]? I mean if the URL is something like : http://mydomain/someotherstring/123-link.html . How to redirect it to http://mydomain/abc/123-link.html?

Comment: In that case, the rule would be: `RewriteRule ^(?!abc/)[^/]+/(.*)$ /abc/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: It didnt work. I still can access  mydomain/someotherstring/123-link.html.

Comment: @NấmLùn Updated the reply above. Test if this one works

Comment: still not works. It redirects to mydomain/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/123-link.html

Comment: @NấmLùn There is some other rule causing this. The configuration above is working for my local setup.